# Jquery Error Uncaught TypeError Object has no method 'wijmenu'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I can call this function in jquery, always gives me this error.
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'wijmenu'

The page with source is at the bottom

This is the wijmo version i used: https://github.com/wijmo/Wijmo-Open

---

heres my html code:

```
<div> 
<ul id='ipodmenu'>
    <li>
        <h3>
            Menu example</h3>
    </li>
    <li></li>
    <li><a href='#'>CSS Library</a> 
        <ul>
            <li><a href='www.google.pt'>Horizontal CSS Menus</a></li>
            <li><a href='http://www.sapo.pt'>Vertical CSS Menus</a></li>
            <li><a href='http://www.facebook.com'>Image CSS</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#'>CSS Drive</a> 
        <ul>
            <li><a href='#4'>Menu Gallery</a> 
                <ul>
                    <li><a href='#5'>Blue Color</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#6'>Green Color</a> 
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href='#5'>Blue Color</a></li>
                            <li><a href='#6'>Green Color</a> 
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href='#5'>Blue Color</a></li>
                                    <li><a href='#6'>Green Color</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href='www.microsoft.pt'>Web Design News</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#'>JavaScript Kit</a> 
        <ul>
            <li><a href='#8'>JavaScript tutorials</a></li>
            <li><a href='#8'>JavaScript Reference</a></li>
            <li><a href='#10'>DOM Reference</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<br style='clear: left' />
```

---

Here the script error
[image: Script Error]

---

And this is the script list
[image]

---

The script list is all defined in  the head seaction

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="wijmoMenu\jquery-wijmo.css" charset="UTF-8" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="wijmoMenu\jquery.wijmo.wijsuperpanel.css" charset="UTF-8" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="wijmoMenu\jquery.wijmo.wijmenu.css" charset="UTF-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="wijmoMenu\jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="wijmoMenu\jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="wijmoMenu\jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="wijmoMenu\jquery.bgiframe-2.1.3-pre.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="wijmoMenu\jquery.wijmo.wijutil.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="wijmoMenu\jquery.wijmo.wijsuperpanel.js"></script>
```

---

IpodMenu Webpage : [Download](http://www.2shared.com/file/Vkrzgiab/ipodMenu.html)

Comment: Did you reference the wijmo script?

Comment: Can you post a link to the site, are you making sure you are linking to this Library in your html?

Comment: Is your script running before `wijmenu` has been defined?

Comment: yes the script list is defined, just add the script list

Comment: just add the source http://www.2shared.com/file/Vkrzgiab/ipodMenu.html

Comment: The scripts you are including are different than the scripts listed on their documentation. Are you using a previous version of wijmo? Specifically, it looks like you are missing the jquery.wijmo-open.all & jquery.wijmo-complete files.

Comment: i'm using this wijmo, https://github.com/wijmo/Wijmo-Open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the fact that you are using the http://github.com/wijmo/Wijmo-Open, then you need to include all files for the features that you wish to be using. In this case, you are using the wijmenu, so you need to include that source file: `jquery.wijmo.wijmenu.js`

Add this to your scripts list in the html, assuming the file is on your server:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="wijmoMenu\jquery.wijmo.wijmenu.js"></script>`

Comment: was that, forget to call that script grrrr. thanks a lot Mattc

Answer (score 0):

According to the wijmo documentation, the `id` needs to be set to "menu" and you've set it to "ipodmenu".

Here is a link to the documentation:
http://wijmo.com/wiki/index.php/Menu#Markup_and_Scripting

Also make sure you are including all wijmo script files as well, you don't have that part of your HTML shown in your question.

Comment: I don't think that is right, I think you just need to select the element you want to call wijmo on, in this cause it is his `ipodmenu`

Comment: @Rchristiani yes, I think you are right, the problem is more likely that the wijmo scripts haven't been included properly in the HTML